# Select text from either a DIV or an underlying container, if it exists

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having a div table where each row has two cells/columns.
The second cell/column sometimes has a clear text (`<div class="something">Text</div>`) while sometimes it's hidden within an "a" tag inside: `<div class="something"><a href="url">Text</a></div>`.

Now, I have no problem in getting everything but the linked text. I can also get the linked text separately, but I don't know how to get everything at once, so I get three columns of data: 
1. first column text, 
2. second column text no matter if it is linked or not, 
3. link, if it exist

The code that extracts everything not linked and works is:

```
times = scrapy.Selector(response).xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " time ")]/text()').extract()
titles = scrapy.Selector(response).xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " name ")]/text()').extract()
for time, title in zip(times, titles):
    print time.strip(), title.strip()
```

I can get the linked items only with

```
ltitles = scrapy.Selector(response).xpath('//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " name ")]/a/text()').extract()
for ltitle in ltitles:
    print ltitle.strip()
```

But don't know how to combine the "query" to get everything together.

Here's a sample HTML:

```
<div class="programRow rowOdd">
  <div class="time ColorVesti">
                        22:55
  </div>
  <div class="name">

                        Dnevnik

  </div>  
</div>

<div class="programRow rowEven">
  <div class="time ColorOstalo">
                        23:15
  </div>

  <div class="name">
    <a class="recnik" href="/page/tv/sr/story/20/rts-1/2434373/kulturni-dnevnik.html" rel="/ajax/storyToolTip.jsp?id=2434373">Kulturni dnevnik</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Sample output (one I cannot get):

```
22:55, Dnevnik, []
23:15, Kulturni dnevnik, /page/tv/sr/story/20/rts-1/2434373/kulturni-dnevnik.html
```

I either get the first two columns (without the linked text) or just the linked text with the code samples above.

Comment: Can you share sample input HTML and explain what you want to get as output?

Comment: @paultrmbrth: Done!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you should probably just iterate through program nodes and create item for every cycle. Also there's xpath shortcut `//text()` which captures all text under the node and it's childrem

Try something like:

```
programs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'programRow')]")
for program in programs:
    item = dict()
    item['name'] = program.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'name')]//text()").extract_first()
    item['link'] = program.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'name')]/a/@href").extract_first()
    item['title'] = program.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'title')]//text()").extract_first()
    return item
```